# Visual Basic biginteger giving me different solutions

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, integer, biginteger

Im trying to make a program that indefinitely generates rows of Pascal's triangle. I was using integers, singles, etc but kept getting overflows and values of "Infinity" so I tried using biginteger and now it gives me different results. I am using visual studio 2012
This was my output for the first few with integer data type:
1 ,
1 , 1 ,
1 , 2 , 1 ,
1 , 3 , 3 , 1 ,

This was my output for the first few with biginteger data type:
 1 ,
 1 , 1 ,
 1 , 2 , 0 ,
 1 , 3 , 3 , 0 ,

The ONLY thing i have changed is the data type. Here is the code for the relevant bit:

```
    n = rows
    val(0) = 1
    For k = 1 To rows
        val(k) = val(k - 1) * (n / k)
        n -= 1
    Next
```

rows is the current row (I have this on a timer_tick so that it can run indefinitely and rows increases by 1 each tick)
How can I get the biginteger data type to return the same values as the integer data type?

Answer (score 0):

EDITED as I realized stackoverflow didnt make your linebreaks,  Integer is 32 bit while bigint is 64 bit.  Fractions can get rounded in different directions when more digits are involved.

To easily avoid rounding errors, you could eliminate division from your code.

e.g.)  Here we have a running string and temp string.  We split the temp string to calculate the next row only using addition and subtraction.

```
    Dim c As String = "1"
    Dim temp As New StringBuilder
    Dim f As New StringBuilder
    temp.Append(c)
    f.Append(temp.ToString)
    For n = 1 To 10
        Dim a() As String = c.Split(",")
        For x = LBound(a) To UBound(a)
            If UBound(a) - LBound(a) >= 1 Then
                If x = UBound(a) Then
                    Dim v1 As UInt32 = a(x - 1)
                    Dim v2 As UInt32 = a(x)
                    temp.Append((v1) + (v2) & "," & 1)
                    c = temp.ToString
                    f.Append(vbCrLf & temp.ToString)
                    temp.Remove(0, temp.Length)
                ElseIf x = LBound(a) Then
                    Dim v1 As UInt32 = a(x)
                    Dim v2 As UInt32 = a(x + 1)
                    temp.Append(1 & "," & (v1) + (v2) & ",")
                ElseIf x < UBound(a) - 1 Then
                    Dim v1 As UInt32 = a(x)
                    Dim v2 As UInt32 = a(x + 1)
                    temp.Append((v1) + (v2) & ",")
                End If
            Else
                temp.Remove(0, temp.Length)
                temp.Append("1,1")
                f.Append(vbCrLf & temp.ToString)
                temp.Remove(0, temp.Length)
                temp.Append("1,2,1")
                f.Append(vbCrLf & temp.ToString)
                c = temp.ToString
                temp.Remove(0, temp.Length)
            End If
        Next
    Next
        MsgBox(f.ToString)
```